# error while uploading a file to url(repository url )

Tags: java, jsp, cloudbees, forge

single_upload_page.jsp:

```
URL url = new URL("https://svn-harini.forge.cloudbees.com/Server1/");
out.println("URL"+url);
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
FileOutputStream fileOut= new FileOutputStream(http.getURL()+saveFile);

fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
```

While deploying its assuming the url as https:/ instead of https:// ....
i need to save a file in forge repository...But when i pass this url i get this error...

Answer (score 0):

Forge repositories are SVN or Git, so I don't think you can upload a file in the way you show.

If you are interested in doing the same class of operations you can do, for example with SVN, then you can check [SVNkit](http://svnkit.com/documentation.html#using-svnit) out, which through SVNClientManager class you get access to a number of interfaces that allow you to perform virtually everything that a Subversion user may need. This includes but not limited to checking out, updating, committing, getting history, differences and browsing repository.

However, please, think that SVN or Git were not created as a file system storage, for that you can use [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), Dropbox, Google Drive or a similar service. We provide the [Amazon S3 ClickStart](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-hibernate-s3-clickstart), which shows you how to upload a file to Amazon S3 once you have an account in Amazon.

Comment: Repository of cloud bees(i.e Forge) also serves the same purpose as Amazon S3.(i.e for storage of files) . If its possible to upload a file via Tortoise SVN ...it should be possible to do it programatically...If my suggestions r wrng..enlighten me..!!!

Comment: Yes, but then you need to cope with the way in which SVN and Git works. So you need to implement the same thing that if you are doing a a commit but programatically. It will be complex.

Comment: The only problem that i get while passing the url is ..Slashes...It is  taking only single slash instead of two... So i tried giving user name and passwd of svn within url..even after which i get the same error..Am able to display or read from the repository but am not able tu write to the repository!!!